# iOS in app purchase event stream keeps firing purchase events after purchase is finished

Tags: ios, flutter, in-app-purchase

I'm working on in-app purchases (non-consumable subscriptions) using the official flutter in_app_purchase package. I start listening to purchaseUpdatedStream as soon as the user opens a page where he can buy a subscription. Once I validate a successful purchase I call completePurchase() method, but purchaseUpdatedStream keeps sending me events with old completed subscriptions even when the subscription is expired. What do I do wrong?
My success purchases processing code:

```
Future<void> _handleSuccess(PurchaseDetails lastPurchase) async {
    var verificationData = lastPurchase.verificationData;

    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      verificationData = await InAppPurchaseConnection.instance.refreshPurchaseVerificationData();
    }

    try {
      if (!await _apiService.verifySubscription(verificationData)) {
        if (Platform.isIOS) {
          await InAppPurchaseConnection.instance.completePurchase(lastPurchase);
        }
        purchasesLogInfo.add('Serverside receipt verification failed');
        _purchasingStatusSink.add(PurchasingState.internalError);
        throw Exception(
            'Purchase with id ${lastPurchase.purchaseID} for product with id ${lastPurchase.productID} verification failed.');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      _purchasingStatusSink.add(PurchasingState.verificationApiConnectionError);
      rethrow;
    }

    purchasesLogInfo.add('Serverside receipt verification successful');

    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      await InAppPurchaseConnection.instance.completePurchase(lastPurchase);
    }

    await updateUserStatus();
    _purchasingStatusSink.add(PurchasingState.successPayment);
  }
```